# Mock a function present in angularJS controller using jest - testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jestjs, controller

I've a small controller written in angularJS.

1st function is actually calling a 2nd one to perform a calculation and return it back.

I want to mock the 2nd function in my testing, so that it returns value I've provided in mock instead of calling the function.

#### ABCService.js

```
var app = angular.module('mathModule', []);

app.controller('mathService', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.first = 0;
    $scope.second = 0;

    $scope.addTwoNumbers = function(x, y) {
        return x + y;
    };

    $scope.callAddFunction = function() {
        return $scope.addTwoNumbers(10, 20);
    }

}]);
```

#### ABCServic.test.js

```
require('./mathService.js');

describe('Math service', function() {

    beforeEach(
        angular.mock.module('mathModule')
    );

    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    describe('Test using 2 numbers', function() {

        var $scope, controller;

        beforeEach(function() {
            $scope = {};
            controller = $controller('mathService', { $scope: $scope });
        });

        it("Nested function", function() {
            var total = $scope.callAddFunction();

            expect(total).toEqual(31);
        });
    });
});
```

Here I want to mock `addTwoNumbers()` so that instead of calling we get value we've provided during testing.

Something like, `Mock(addTwoNumbers(x,y)) = 0`, so now callAddFunction will return 0 instead of 30, which it should be returning if not mocked.